# Move ImageView from 1 layout to another

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

As you see below I have a before and after picture. In the first one, I have a toolbar which is inflated through my `BaseActivity`. Below the toolbar, I inflate a `Fragment` with an `ImageView` below the activity. So to clearify, I have a fragment with a picture which is inflated under an activity. The activity itself handles the toolbar which is above said fragment.

**Before**

[image: Before]

After an animation, I want the ImageView to go from being an `ImageView` inside my `Fragment` to being an `ImageView` in my `Toolbar`.(1)

**After**

[image: After]

The animation itself will be to resize and move up to the toolbar(as shown in **"After"**).

The problem i'm having is that I don't know how to move the `ImageView` from one layout to another.(2)

**Question**

(1). Is this even resonable to do?

(2). Is there a way to "detach" an ImageView from its parent into another layout?

**Conclusion**

So, 1 last time. I want to move my ImageView from the Fragment into the Activities toolbar.

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. We send the ImageView from the Fragment to the Activity and after that we start the animation from its original position into the toolbar.
2. We let the ImageView animate within the fragment but over the toolbar(If possible?) and when the animation finishes the fragment is closed and an image is set into the toolbar.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about "shared element transition", right?

Comment: You mean, actually something like facebook messenger bubbles? You want to be able to hold & move the ImageView ?

Comment: @StasLelyuk Wow, that actually looks exactly like what i'm trying to do, thanks a lot! I will look into that

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan Not really, I will add an onClick method to it later so it will move by itself.

Comment: Well, in this case you can set it programatically to GONE, but before that define a transition into your anim folder and call it . It is not probably the best way to make it(i'm sure about that) but is a thing I've made similarry (without the showing into the toolbar part)

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan Big thanks, you might have just saved me a couple of days :) I will try to get something working.